# write array starting from specific column to new workbook using xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

I am trying to write an array (data = [][]) to a worksheet I will create using xlwt.
My question is can I specify a column to start from?  I am planning to use a for loop to iterate through the array retrieving the values row by row starting a new line with each row ex: first row starts at C1, next row starts at C2 etc...  I have read the documentation and examples but cannot find a clear way to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Insert two blank cells at the front of each row?

Comment: The examples are included in the documentation if one knows where to look...  Also typing the first '(' will often give a description of the parameters a method accepts and what they do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
for r, row in enumerate(data):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(r, 2 + c, label=col)
```